# PyQt Pushbutton click and release handler

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to add a function when the button is clicked.

Another function when it is released.

The clicked.connect method only fires a function when the button is released, so it won't work in my case.

```
button.clicked.connect()
```

Comment: @MikeSadler. That's because there is a preponderance of poorly written questions throughout the SO site. The OP could have easily found this information for themselves by simply [consulting the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#signals). The principle reason for downvoting a question is that it "does not show any research effort" - so any downvotes seem fully justified. [Disclaimer: I did not vote either way on this question].

Comment: I am sorry for my unresearched question @ekhumoro I will try to not do this again in the future.

Comment: @Soundwave. Thanks for responding. My comment wasn't meant as a direct criticism of you. The only aim is to encourage people improve their questions, which helps the SO community as a whole.

Comment: @ekhumoro - I know it was a basic question, but sometimes the examples beginners use don't point towards the reference documentation.  He was obviously new to this, so I pointed him towards the documentation in my answer - which I thought was more constructive than just downvoting.  I've been the victim of a completely unexplained downvote - and I still don't know what it was for (it was a difficult C++ question that I've only recently got to the bottom of).  I think downvoting ought to be accompanied by an explanation, otherwise people can't learn from it.

Comment: And on that note, someone downvoted my answer below (there's a +1 and a -1) - again, I am unsure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
button.clicked.connect(...)
button.pressed.connect(...)
button.released.connect(...)
```

You can connect more than 1 signals to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractbutton.html, "pressed" is the signal you are looking for.

Generally with PyQt, try the PyQt docs first - checking all the inherited functionality as well - then if you are still unsure, check the full QT documentation (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpushbutton.html).  This can often give you an insight - although it takes a while to get your eye in.